# hazelcast 3.5: Configuration exception

Tags: java, scala, hazelcast

i am using `jdk11` and `scala 2.12` with `sbt 1.2.8` and `hazelcast 3.5`

here is my hazelcast.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.5.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <network>
        <join>

            <multicast enabled ="true">
                <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
                <multicast-time-to-live>32</multicast-time-to-live>
                <multicast-timeout-seconds>5</multicast-timeout-seconds>
                <trusted-interfaces>
                    <interface>192.168.1.2</interface>
                </trusted-interfaces>
            </multicast>

            <tcp-ip enabled="false">
            </tcp-ip>
            <aws enabled ="false">
            </aws>
        </join>
    </network>

    <group>
        <name>development</name>
    </group>

    <map name = "default">
        <backup-count>1</backup-count>
        <async-backup-count>1</async-backup-count>
        <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds><!-- 0 means infinite maximum time data can remain in mao used or not -->
        <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds> <!-- 0 means infinite maximum time data can remain unused in map -->
        <max-size policy="PER_NODE">0</max-size>  <!--maximum size of the map 0 means infinite -->
        <eviction-policy>LFU</eviction-policy>
        <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
        <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy</merge-policy>
        <cache-deserialized-values>INDEX-ONLY</cache-deserialized-values>
    </map>

</hazelcast>
```

here is my code

```
val hcast = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config)
```

but i am getting following exception

```
 Apr 09, 2019 4:59:57 PM com.hazelcast.config.ClasspathXmlConfig
INFO: Configuring Hazelcast from 'hazelcast.xml'.
[error] (run-main-11) com.hazelcast.config.InvalidConfigurationException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":cache-deserialized-values}'. One of '{"http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":statistics-enabled, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":optimize-queries, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":eviction-percentage, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":min-eviction-check-millis, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":read-backup-data, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":map-store, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":near-cache, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":wan-replication-ref, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":indexes, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":entry-listeners, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":partition-lost-listeners, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":partition-strategy, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":quorum-ref, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":query-caches}' is expected.
[error] com.hazelcast.config.InvalidConfigurationException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":cache-deserialized-values}'. One of '{"http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":statistics-enabled, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":optimize-queries, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":eviction-percentage, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":min-eviction-check-millis, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":read-backup-data, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":map-store, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":near-cache, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":wan-replication-ref, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":indexes, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":entry-listeners, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":partition-lost-listeners, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":partition-strategy, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":quorum-ref, "http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":query-caches}' is expected.
[error]     at com.hazelcast.config.AbstractXmlConfigHelper.schemaValidation(AbstractXmlConfigHelper.java:193)
[error]     at com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigBuilder.parseAndBuildConfig(XmlConfigBuilder.java:211)
[error]     at com.hazelcast.config.XmlConfigBuilder.build(XmlConfigBuilder.java:194)
[error]     at com.hazelcast.config.ClasspathXmlConfig.<init>(ClasspathXmlConfig.java:100)
[error]     at com.hazelcast.config.ClasspathXmlConfig.<init>(ClasspathXmlConfig.java:57)
[error]     at com.hazelcast.config.ClasspathXmlConfig.<init>(ClasspathXmlConfig.java:44)
[error]     at HazelcastServer$.getHcastInstance(HazelcastServer.scala:18)
[error]     at HazelcastServer$.main(HazelcastServer.scala:9)
[error]     at HazelcastServer.main(HazelcastServer.scala)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[error] Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] (Compile / run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 0 s, completed Apr 9, 2019, 4:59:57 PM
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: which specific version is it? 3.5.2?

Answer (score 0):

I saw the post from Hazelcast author. I wonder if the fix is reflected now or not.

He himself claims this configuration error fix to be merged in specific version of Hazelcast (3.5.2). Pull request (https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/pull/5659) solves the problem , though he does not claims for exact date. Here is the link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hazelcast/ogPzxJSp2zc  for conversation. Look at the bottom most thread comment.

You can go in detail to see the whole issue in detail. https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/5551 .